# IE8 Alignment Issue for div as a table

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

My Application works good on IE8+ if I include 
           `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">`tag
But When I Make IE=8 the div is misplaced (where in I have used Div As Table)

Also IN IE=8(+)
top : expression(document.getElementById("abcd").scrollTop-1); (for keeping header Constant when scrolling Tbody)
doesnt works, but it works when I Make IE=7
If I Make IE=7, the DIV gets misplaced...
Is There any alternative for the above expression which will work in IE=8+. (for just makin the table header THEAD constant while scrolling the content)

Please Help regarding This Issue.
I Have Been Trying since A Week Ago but hasn't come with the solution

Comment: Didn't you mean JavaScript instead of Java?

Comment: Create jsfiddle and then update your post giving the link

Comment: Have you tried the `fixed` value for the CSS [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) rule to prevent an element from moving on scroll? It keeps it fixed with respect to the viewport, as opposed to the other page elements like other values would do.

Comment: But <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
doesnt allow
 top : expression(document.getElementById("abcd").scrollTop-1);
it Needs IE=7